# Vc++ Database connectivity Issue

Tags: visual-c++, connectivity

We are using VC++ to connect to the SQl2005 Express in my local machine.
But we are able to access when there is network connectivity to my system.
But we are not able to access when we are removed the network connectivity.

Please help me out if any one faced with this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you use an IP for your system, this will happen; because, when network connectivity is lost, the IP will be lost as well. Use localhost instead. I guess it would solve this issue.